# Need help making top nav menu stick with primary menu and adding social media icons

Tags: web, menu, header, sticky

Trying to make the top nav bar stick while scrolling like the main nav does when scrolling, and need to add social media icons to the left of the top bar. Website is http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/ any help is greatly appreciated. :)

i tried adding position: sticky but no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Horizontal Navigation Bar w/Rollover Effect</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

 #navbar ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    } 

--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="navbar"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li> 
    <li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the top black navbar stick to the page when user scrolls down,

```
  #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
  }
```

This will place the element on top of the page when user scrolls, but you will have a new problem. The black navbar now overlaps the slidein Main menu that appears when user scrolls. So, you will need to place the slidein Main menu below the top black nav bar. This can be achieved by setting:

```
  nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }
```

Adding social icons will need additional markup in your HTML code.

Comment: thank you so much! the top bar worked perfectly, but I am a little confused as to where to add the second code.

Comment: Place it somewhere just like you placed the first code.